# Playing a movie/DVD on a website

Tags: javascript, flash, video-streaming, html5-video, flash-video

I'm trying to play a movie (ripped from a DVD using handbreak to mp4 format, then using Miro to convert to webm) on a website - it works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE6/IE7 just displays a black screen.

I'm using [videojs](http://videojs.com/) but the Flash fallback was not activating, I believe this is because it was trying to view the external .swf file which I've now hosted locally (it's on https) but I still cannot get the video to run:

https://secure.photofileltd.co.uk/new_site/index.php?page=video

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, unfortunately they have said they don't want the video hosted on YouTube or Vimeo...

Thanks!

(edit) just tested and it won't work in IE8/9 either, bah...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few notes: 1) if you deactive flash, you won t see anything in IE6-8 since they don t support HMTL5 2) did you add the type to your source tag? (ceck example at the bottom) 3) i downloaded your mp4 and played it directly in IE9 which works fine. this means it might be a problem with your server configuration. tipp nr. 1 add MIME-Types via .htaccess file to your server

```
//.htaccess 
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .mov
AddType video/webm .webm
```

if this doesn t work, try it without video-js just to make sure the mistake doesn t occure within the video-js frameworks (f.e. wrong/bad codec)

```
<video poster="movie.jpg" controls>
  <source src='movie.webm' type='video/webm'/>
  <source src='movie.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>
  <source src='movie.mp4' type='video/mp4'/>
  <p>Your browser doesn t support html5.</p>
</video>
```

Comment: Huge thanks for the reply, using the latter example, how would I get that to run in IE6-IE8?

Comment: the latter example won t work in ie6-ie8. html5 is not (and will never be) supported for those version. for ie6-ie8 you need to use flash or similar (f.e. html embed tag).