# Got '206 Partial Content' Status on requesting webm videos from my server

Tags: macos, xampp, html5-video

I'm using **XAMPP** server on my **MAC**.
I've created a page which has a **video** tag on it ! (i'm using **video.js** framework)
The video file doesn't play, When i check it on **firebug** (the plugin on **firefox**) ,the **GET** operation returns **'206 Partial Content'** status for that file.

How can i make it work ?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer of longilong works great. I just want to explain how to add mime-types which i wasn't know until i had some googling.

1- create a text file named '.htaccess' in the directory of your site (the path where your pages exists)

> *the htaccess file is just a apache configuration file which override the main apache configurations for just that path which it resides*

2- add these lines to your new .htaccess file:

```
# Audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg
AddType audio/mp4                      m4a

# Video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v
AddType video/webm                     webm
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, WebM is supported in Firefox 4+. This error also could occur, if your server is not well configured. for example if the mime-types are not added. check this post here: [Playing a movie/DVD on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728977/playing-a-movie-dvd-on-a-website/9736361#9736361) .hope it helps

Comment: Thank you longilong, I added mime-types in .htaccess file and it works :)