# iPad alpha on video tag

Tags: ipad, html, mobile-safari, html5-video

Well I have a burning issue, with the iPad.. more specifically Safari on the iPad.

The  tag doesn't play .mov's at all and converting using Quicktime to .m4v loses my alpha layer.

Currently working with a PNG sequence but its horrible.. Is there any way I can keep my alpha channel and have the video tag work?

Many thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that the iPad doesn't support the alpha channel (or at least every method and format I tried wouldn't work) and it wouldn't play the video because Apple have disabled the autoplay attribute

But I did make a workaround, there appears to be a buffer at page load in which you can start the play() function on a video and stop it meaning its ready to play. But you can only get one video in...

Bummer..

Answer (score 0):

html5-video is able to play mov-files! usually this happens, if the server isn t well configured with the MIME-type of the video. check my answer here [Playing a movie/DVD on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728977/playing-a-movie-dvd-on-a-website/9736361#9736361) maybe this solves your mov problem and you don t have to use .m4v at all

Comment: its the alpha layer I'm interested in as its overlaying an image but on the iPad it won't play .mov's and won't play nice with m4v's I've tried putting a H264 in an MPEG4 container with an alpha layer but nothing and I've tried the canvas "buffer" trick but that didn't work either..

Comment: Also, I checked the MIME types and everything to deliver video content is set in place, we've opted for a PNG sequence now so its not an issue.

Comment: Be aware that playing .mov files on the web is not a good idea because of the very large filesize as compared to .h264 video. The alpha channel supporting video codecs supported by .mov generate very large files. A better structural approach is to use a mixed alpha + rgb set of videos and then compose them int a RGBA video before playing them. For example see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079559/763355